# IntelliJ gradle integration issue with independent gradle subprojects

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have two independent gradle projects that I also want to build from one main gradle project:

```
main-project
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle

  --subproject-one
      build.gradle
      settings.gradle

      --module-a
           build.gradle

  --subproject-two
      build.gradle
      settings.gradle

      --module-b
          build.gradle
```

My top settings.gradle includes all modules from the sub projects:

```
file('subproject-one').eachDir { dir ->
  if(dir.list().contains("build.gradle")) {
    include dir.name
    project(":${dir.name}").projectDir = dir
  }
}
file('subproject-two').eachDir { dir ->
  if(dir.list().contains("build.gradle")) {
    include dir.name
    project(":${dir.name}").projectDir = dir
  }
}
```

Now i have a dependency from *module-b* in *subproject-two* to *module-a* in *subproject-one*. I use a compile switch (useProjectDependencies) to include them as project dependencies when I build from the main project and as normal dependencies when i build from the subprojects:

```
if(useProjectDependencies){
    compile project(':module-b')
} else {
    //Client dependencies
    compile "my.group.id:module-b
}
```

Via gradle I'm now able to build the main-project including the subproject and also each subproject on it's own.

When I open the main-project now via IntelliJ I see all the modules are recognized correctly and also the cross references to classes between the modules work correctly (refactoring interface between to components are working great).

When I now try to use the gradle integration from Intellij and click on assemble for the *module-b* then it **incorrectly uses the *build.gradle* form and *settings.gradle* from *subproject-two*** and doesn't use the project dependencies. It looks like IntelliJ or the gradle daemon searches for the first settings.gradle in a bottom up way from the *module-b* instead of using the one in the *main-project*.

When I build via terminal from the *main-project* folder all works correctly:

```
gradlew :module-b:assemble //correct *settings.gradle* and *build.gradle* is used
```

When I delete the  *settings.gradle* and *build.gradle* from *subproject-two* then the build.gradle from the *main-project* is correctly used.

Is there a way to specify the *settings.gradle* and *build.gradle* that is used as part of the IntelliJ gradle integration?

Comment: Try to specify the working directory in Run Configuration as the directory from `main-project`.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but then i need to do this for every possible gradle task I want to execute which is quite cumbersome.